# Convert each element in a flat array into a subarray containing the element's original value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My array looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
)
```

Desired array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
        )
)
```

I have gone through these links but didn't able to figure out the solution being a newbie.

[Convert associative array into indexed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888847/convert-associative-array-into-indexed)

[convert indexed multidimensional array to associative multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935031/convert-indexed-multidimensional-array-to-associative-multidimensional-array)

Comment: there is no inbuilt function for it, so you need to loop over the current array and build your expected output, 1 line of code

Comment: For lolz, https://3v4l.org/Qko24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a blanket statement on how to get your desired array :**

```
$desired_array = array(array("0"=>"A"), array("0"=>"B"), array("0"=>"C"));
```

**However, dynamically, you could do the following :**

```
//Assume $original_array = array("0"=>"A", "1"=>"B", "2"=>"C");

$desired_array = array(); // New Array
for($i = 0; $i < count($original_array); $i++){ // Loop over all elements in original array
array_push($desired_array, array("0"=>$original_array[$i])); // Place each valueable as an array in new desired array
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For example:

```
$new_array = array_map(
    function ($v) { return [$v]; }, 
    ['A', 'B', 'C']
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrOld = ['A','B','C','D','E'];
$arrNew = [];
foreach($arrOld as $key => $value){
    $arrNew[] = [$key => $value];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the following snippets provide the same result. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mDA7V))

- Break the array into 1-element chunks:

  ```
  var_export(array_chunk($array, 1));
  ```
- Map each element to be cast as a 1-element array containing the original value:

  ```
  var_export(array_map(fn($v) => (array) $v, $array));
  ```
- Map each element to be the single value in a subarray

  ```
  var_export(array_map(fn($v) => [$v], $array));
  ```
- Use a body-less loop with a pair of square braces to push each value as the lone child of a new element.

  ```
  $result = [];
  foreach ($array as $result[][]);
  var_export($result);
  ```